# How can I append a state object in react

Tags: reactjs

```
  const [arr, setArr] = useState({
      value: [],
        });
```

//I want to append the value on the state object but its overwriting it.

```
  setArr((prevState) => ({
                    ...arr,
                    value: [...prevState.value, res.data],
                }));
```

Comment: Replace `...arr` with `...prevState` and you're golden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set new state by comparing old state data and push new data inside **setArr function**.

So your new code will be:

```
setArr((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  value: [...prevState.value, res.data],
}));
```